# Class with static instance inside

Tags: c#, visual-studio, design-patterns

```
public class MyClass
{
    // private fields


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public MyClass(string param1, string param2)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }

    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private static volatile MyClass instance = null;

    public static MyClass  Log
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new MyClass();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private MyClass()
    {
        // do some stuff
    }

    public void myFunction(string txt, uint flags)
    {
         // do some stuff
    }
}
```

This is my class and I use it this way

```
    MyClass.Log.myFunction("some string", flags);
```

But constantly get that either MyClass is null or MyClass.Log is null when i use this class in other class functions.

What do I do wrong?

In addition to the question here is the error i get:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MyNamespace.MyClass..ctor()
   at MyNamespace.MyClass.get_Log()
```

Comment: What have this to do with C++?

Comment: I tried the code, nothing was wrong!

Comment: Please show the code of the parameterless constructor. This code is throwing the exception.

Comment: so many answers, they disappeared :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you showed looks good.
`MyClass` can't be `null` as it is a class. `Log` shouldn't be `null` either, your singleton implementation looks OK.

My guess is that the problem is that you are using the parameterless constructor of `MyClass`. I guess that `myFunction` somehow uses something that is only initialized in the constructor that takes the two parameters.

Actually, according to your stack trace the problem is inside the parameterless constructor. I guess you are trying to log something in there, like this : `instance.Log(...);`. That won't work, because at that point `instance` is still `null`. You should simply use `Log(...)` instead.